# How to prevent malicious scripts writing to Firebase database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I been reading firebase 3+ documentation for a while and I'm still wondering how to manage the following scenario regarding safety:

Let say I have a website for publishing local business like yellow pages in where everyone with an account can add new entries and edit the info of the existing ones with the following schema:

```
{
    "businesses"": {    
        "62061635": {
            "id": "62061635",
            "name": "Cellphone store"
        },
        "66856728": {
            "id": "66856728",
            "name": "El Bambino restaurant"
        }
    }
}
```

If a user with a successful login write the following snipped in the developers console:

```
firebase.database().ref('/businesses/').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

Practically all users could retrieve all the businesses info, that's not so drastic, but if instead of the above code the users use the following code:

```
var i=0;
while(i++ < 10) {
    var id = generateRandomString();
    firebase.database().ref('businesses/' + id).set({
        id: id,
        name: generateRandomString()
    });
}
```

That's something I worry about, I know there are rules for database, but in this case where all users can add and edit the info, how can I prevent the users to run *malicious* scripts like the ones above?

Comment: If you want to allow everyone to read/add/edit this "malicious scripts"  will be possible. If you dont you should work on your rules like setting some validations when writing and reduce the scope on who have this permission.

Comment: You need to define what 'all users' means. By default a user has to be authenticated to read/write to Firebase (v3.x) so that's the first step. The next step is to define which user can write and where they can write to. In other words define how a user becomes a user to start with. Once you have that, you can put rules in place to control reading and writing. i.e. a Rule would be: only allow users to write a node where that node contains the user id.

Comment: Yes, I agree, but let me put this example: imagine I'm building a site like Wikipedia or Wikia, where everyone with an account can add new entries to the website and is able to edit the info in order to get more accurate content. How would be the rules for a project like that if everyone can add/edit?

Comment: @SergioFlores, any ideas? Still trying to solve this.